# Rendering Video in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, video

Is there a good solution for playing a compressed video in OpenGL?

It needs to

- Be cross-platform (Windows and MacOSX)
- Render to a texture (preferably but not 100% needed)
- Cost less than Bink

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the [Theora video format.](http://www.theora.org/)
Here are the benefits:

- Totally open, free and patent-unencoumbered specification
- Free working library implementation (encoder/decoder) and source-code examples, available under a BSD-style license
- Not too shabby documentation.
- Portable

The decoder lets you decode to R'G'B', which can easily be uploaded with an OpenGL buffer object and fetched in a shader via a sampler.

Answer (score 6):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products) can be used to render widgets (including a video player) in an OpenGL scene.  It has a multimedia framework called phonon that can play video and audio.

See this [demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXS3xKV-UM0).

Qt is cross-platform and is now licensed under LGPL.

Comment: Good answer, impressive demo, but our company is looking to avoid QT.

Comment: I know this question is old but : Why do you try to avoid Qt?  Nothing prevents you to use it freely in commercial products since version 4.5 is published under LGPL.

Comment: Or alternatively, who do you work for so I can remember to avoid them? ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you mean by solution that you can build/code it, i can suggest quicktime (easy on mac with cocoa, strange on windows but it works) or you can checkout mplayer/vlc sources and try to integrate that. there are a lot of demos about this on the web.

since you need cross platform, i guess gstreamer, video4linux and directshow are nothing for you. but there are video players that support different backends on different platforms - like [openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc)